# Javascript cant reset object in module

Tags: javascript

```
const Player = (name, mark) => {
    let markedSpots = [];

    const markSpot = (spot) => {
        markedSpots.push(spot); 
    };

    const clearSpots = () => {
        markedSpots = [];
    };  

    return {name, mark, markedSpots, markSpot, clearSpots};
};

let player1 = Player('Player 1', 'X');
let player2 = Player('Player 2', 'O');

const gameLogic = (() => {
    let currentPlayer = player1;

    const reset = () => {

        player1.clearSpots();
        player2.clearSpots();
        currentPlayer = player1;
    };

    return {startGame, reset};
})();
```

Above I have part of the code from a tictactoe game that I am trying to make. In the reset function I need to clear the array in the both player objects and set the current player back to player1. Through debugging, I know that calling the clearSpots() function does clear the array in the player objects. But there is a problem with reseting the currentPlayer. I believe this might be a closure problem, but I have no idea how to identify the problem or how to solve it. CAn anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you call `markedSpots = [];`, you're **changing the `markedSpots` reference**.

This means that the returned `markedSpots` from earlier is **not** being changed, and instead only the `markedSpots` variable inside of the function's value is. When you try to access the returned `markedSpots` outside of the `Player` function, it is still referencing the original value, not the new empty one.

What you can do is replace `markedSpots = [];` with **`markedSpots.splice(0, markedSpots.length);`**, which will empty the array without changing the reference.

```js
const Player = (name, mark) => {
    let markedSpots = [];

    const markSpot = (spot) => {
        markedSpots.push(spot); 
    };

    const clearSpots = () => {
        markedSpots.splice(0, markedSpots.length);  // <= Change is here.
    };  

    return {name, mark, markedSpots, markSpot, clearSpots};
};

let player1 = Player('Player 1', 'X');
let player2 = Player('Player 2', 'O');

const gameLogic = (() => {
    let currentPlayer = player1;

    const reset = () => {

        player1.clearSpots();
        player2.clearSpots();
        currentPlayer = player1;
    };

    return {reset};
})();

// Testing (should output two empty arrays):

player1.markSpot(1);
player1.markSpot(2);
player2.markSpot(3);

gameLogic.reset();

console.log(player1.markedSpots)
console.log(player2.markedSpots)
```

Comment: could you explain on how that prevents the new one from being accessed?

Comment: @dnguy104 OK, I've edited my answer with more detail. Basically, when you had `markedSpots = []` it was changing the local variable but not the reference that had already been returned earlier. Instead, if you use `splice`, you're editing the same reference, not creating a new one.

Comment: I think i'm starting to understand it now. thanks. Is it correct to say that the markedSpots that is returned and that markedSpots within the function are two separate objects trying to reference the same value. but i was only changing the value for the markedSpots within the function. The same mistake could've been made from outside with "player1.markedSpots = []". By using splice, i keep the original value so that both markedSpots can access it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a class instead. You could use the `class` syntax:

- create a constructor with the player initialization logic saving the variables in `this` as properties
- add methods to the class: here `markSpot` and `clearSpots`
- instantiate new objects with `new`: `let players1 = new Player(...)`

Here is a code example:

```js
class Player {

  constructor(name, mark) {
    
    this.markedSpots = [];
    this.mark = mark;
    this.name = name;
    
    return this;
  
  }
    
  markSpot(spot) {
    this.markedSpots.push(spot); 
  };

  clearSpots() {
    this.markedSpots = [];
  };
  
};

let player1 = new Player('Player 1', 'X');
let player2 = new Player('Player 2', 'O');

const gameLogic = (() => {
    let currentPlayer = player1;

    const reset = () => {

        player1.clearSpots();
        player2.clearSpots();
        currentPlayer = player1;
    };

    return {reset}; // removed startGame for demo purposes
})();

player1.markSpot(1);
console.log('before:', player1)

gameLogic.reset();

console.log('after:', player1)
```

Notice how you can access the object's property when inside the class with `this`: `this.markedSpots`, `this.mark`, `this.name` etc...

Comment: Ya, I think this would be the easier way to go